# Help to use FIX (financial information exchange protocol) in application

Tags: java, fix-protocol

I am coding on server side for related to financial application in java using proprietary protocol but some one suggested to me that to use FIX (financial information exchange protocol) in place of proprietary protocol currently i don't have any idea regarding FIX so if you have any idea or some guidance (code/example) that how to use FIX in application then please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

[FIX is an electronic communications protocol for international real-time exchange of information related to the securities transactions and markets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIX_protocol) FIX is used extensively in the financial industry, I would be surprised to see any financial institution not using FIX.

You can do trading, get quotes, get market data, news etc using FIX. Messages from one party to another party is formatted using FIX, only messaging and identification of the other party, no networking is involved at all. Networking is left for the user of the protocol, how he wants to transfer the messages.

Reference for construction of [FIX messages](http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXimate3.0/)

[QuickfixJ](http://www.quickfixj.org/) is an open source library, in Java, for developers wanting to use FIX messaging. There are other commercial alternatives also i.e. CameronFIX etc. QuickfixJ is a simplistic library and quite easy to understand. There are 2 examples for using the library, included, which you can try it out yourself.

Comment: Thanks, to tell me about FIX if possible then please help me that how to use it in application and if any jar/library is require for it then please suggest link from where i able to download it

Comment: @user441507 - I gave the link of QuickfixJ in my answer. QuickfixJ is a fix engine, download it and try running the sample applications provided in the code.

Comment: Thanks, as you suggested me i got link for downloading the QuickfixJ engine(Quickfix-1.13.3) is it right?

Comment: You are trying to download the C++ engine rather than the Java. Quickfix is the C++ version, QuickfixJ is the Java version

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a [text layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIX_protocol).

For internal communications between components of your app it doesn't matter.

If you're talking to the outside world, then you'd need to follow some format, be it FIX or [FpML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FpML) (which is arguably more common)

Comment: This varies between market sectors.  In the case of Stock / ETD exchange connectivity for trading, FIX is definitely the standard, with numerous dialects.  FAST is common for market data, but for direct connectivity we often see proprietary binary protocols as well.

Answer (score -1):

[Here is their official website](http://www.fixprotocol.org/what-is-fix.shtml). Go through their introduction and basic presentations and check if FIX fits your needs. Even if it doesn't you can get an idea for preparing your own custom data exchange format.